# Is the expectation of a random vector multiplied by its transpose equal to the product of the expectation of the vector and that of the transpose

Tags: expected-value, covariance, linear-algebra

I'm taking a course in advance statistics and we have to prove whether the following expression is true: $E[zz^T]=E[z]E[z^T]$. I am assuming it is not, since the formula of the covariante matrix is $Cov(z)=E[zz^T]-E[z]E[z^T]$. However, I don't know how can I prove that.

Answer (score 16):

To confirm a claim is not true, you don't "prove it".  Instead, just provide a counterexample would be sufficient.

You are actually on the right track.  Any random vector $z$ with positive definite covariance matrix would disprove this claim.  For example, let $z \sim N_2(0, I_{(2)})$.  Then $E[zz^\top] = \operatorname{Cov}(z) = I_{(2)}$, while $E[z]E[z^\top] = 0$.  In fact, this conjecture is false even for any non-degenerate univariate distribution (e.g., $z \sim N(0, 1)$), as a result of $\operatorname{Var}(z) = E[z^2] - (E[z])^2 > 0$.

Comment: Another "easy" mismatch is that $E[z]E[z^\top]$ is a rank 1 matrix while $E[z z^\top]$ will often have full rank.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a discrete counter-example, if that's easier to wrap your head around.

Let

$$
\begin{align}
P(z_0=1 \wedge z_1=1) &= 0.5 \\
P(z_0=-1 \wedge z_1=-1) &= 0.5
\end{align}
$$

Then

$$
E[z] = 0 \\
E[zz^T] = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$